# javascript - why does map return null array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

this mapping is supposed to append the result of the query inside to each object.

```
var newobj = obj.map(function (frequentPosition) {
    var query = `SQL query that uses attributes of obj`;
    sequelize.query(query).then(result => {
       obj.newArrayAttribute = result[0]; 
       return obj;
       });
    });
```

newobj returned is an array of undefined

Comment: You never `return` anything from the `map` callback

Comment: Just return the Promise, and call `Promise.all` on the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you do mutate theobjects asynchronously, however you do not wait for the async calls to finish thats why it looks as if the objects were never changed. Additionally you do not return anything from inside the `.map`, therefore `newobj` is an array of `undefined`s.

`sequelize.query(query)` already returns a promise, if you return that from the `.map` callback, you end up with an array of promises, which you can turn into a Promise that resolves to an array using `Promise.all`:

```
   const promise = Promise.all(obj.map(frequentPosition => {
    var query = `SQL query that uses attributes of obj`;
    return sequelize.query(query).then(result => {
      return { ...obj, newAttribute: result[0], };
    });
  });
```

Then you can use the promise as:

```
  promise.then(newobj => {
    // Do stuff with newobj
  });
```

Comment: this just returns Promise { <pending> }

Comment: @emma3 yup, thats exactly what you need. [Read on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: this appends all the new query results to the end of the array. I want queries to be executed per object and the result to be added to that object.

Comment: @emma3 well returning `obj` from the promise might not be what you want ... Yet you haven't used `frequentPosition`.